# Find the number of Detail records and update the count column of the Master table

Tags: sql-server

I use SQL Server 2014 for my project. I have two tables (master and detail relationship) as follows:

```
Master:
id
detail_count (the number of associated Detail records)

Detail:
id
master_id
```

The column `detail_count` is the number of Detail records a Master record has. I am able to find the count for each Master record as follows:

```
select m.id, count(*) from Master m
join Detail d on d.master_id = m.id
group by m.id
```

I am also able to write the update statement for the Master table:

```
update Master set detail_count = ?
```

How can I combine the above two statements to update the detail_count for all Master records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply update the count using below query:

```
update Master 
set detail_count = (select count(*) from detail where detail.master_id = Master.id)
```

Comment: This is smart! Thank you!